# Not been able to execute java program using batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I am facing a issue while executing a java program using a batch file.

My batch file looks like -

`java  -cp .;/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar;/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;/lib/junit-4.11.jar;/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar;/lib/poi-3.11-20141221.jar;/lib/poi-examples-3.11-20141221.jar;/lib/poi-excelant-3.11-20141221.jar;/lib/poi-ooxml-3.11-20141221.jar;/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221.jar;/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.11-20141221.jar;/lib/xmlbeans-2.5.0.jar; com.migrate.MigrUtil`

The lib folder is in the same directory as of the batch file.
But its not been able to detect the jar file. Its works fine when I mention the absolute path to the jars file e.g `c:\test\lib\commons-codec-1.9.jar`

Any help on this guys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problems is that you specify `/lib/...` instead of `lib/...`. As a result, the system looks to the root of your filesystem for the jars.